# Abel's binomial theorem

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-theorem

Abel's generalization of the binomial theorem goes as follows

$$(a+x)^n=x^n+ \sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i} a(a+iz)^{i-1}(x-iz)^{n-i}$$

The objective is to prove the generalization by induction. My first step following the textbook was to set $n=k$ and integrate both sides with respect to $x$, in order to obtain; $$\frac {(a+x)^{k+1}}{k+1}=\frac {x^{k+1}}{k+1}+ \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i} \frac {a(a+iz)^{i-1}(x-iz)^{k-i+1}}{k-i+1} + C$$

The next step was to find the value of the integration constant $C$ by setting $x=(k+1)z$ in the formula above and use the inductive hypothesis. This is the part where I got stuck and cannot seem to figure it out...

$$\frac {(a+z(k+1))^{k+1}}{k+1}=\frac {(z(k+1))^{k+1}}{k+1}+ \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i} \frac {a(a+iz)^{i-1}(z(k+1)-iz)^{k-i+1}}{k-i+1} + C$$

I see how multiplying both sides by $k+1$ would give us $$(a+z(k+1))^{k+1}= (z(k+1))^{k+1}+\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k+1}{i} a(a+iz)^{i-1}(z(k+1)-iz)^{k-i+1}+ C$$
where, again, $(k+1)z=x$. But I still am confused as to determining $C$. It was previously tried by setting $z=0$, that is $C(a,0)$ for $C(a,z)$, where $a,z \in \mathbb {R}$. But this computes only for $z$, and therefore the answer could not hold...

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(x-iz)^{n-i}$ in the first line?

Comment: @Gary; I do not see which line you are referring to...

Comment: Right after "Abel's generalization of the binomial theorem goes as follows" in the sum the power should be $n-i$ and not $n-1$.

Comment: @Gary; Wow, didn't even notice the mistake, thank you. Do you have an idea on what step one might take towards determining $C$?

Comment: $x=(k+1)$ or $x=(k+1)z$?

Comment: @Gary; $x=(k+1)z$

Comment: You get $(k+1)C$ in the end, because you multiplied both sides by $k+1$. If you write everything properly, you see that you must show that $C = C(a,z) = \frac{{a(a + iz)^k }}{{k + 1}}$.

Comment: @Gary; Could you post you answer below?

Comment: The answer below computes only $C(a,0)$ and therefore does not answer your question.

Comment: @epi163sqrt You showed that it does.

Comment: You are telling:  *".. and integrate both sides with respect to $x$ in order to obtain .. "*
But why are you taking the indefinite integral and not $\int_{x = 0}^y {f(x)dx} $ ?

Comment: @Aristarchus_: Answer revised. Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we complete OPs proof by induction. Note, we will employ the induction hypothesis twice. Assuming $a\ne 0$ we can write OPs version of Abel's binomial theorem somewhat more convenient as:

\begin{align*}
(a+x)^k&=\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k}{q}a(a+qz)^{q-1}(x-qz)^{k-q}\tag{1.1}
\end{align*}
The induction step we want to show is

**Induction step:**
\begin{align*}
(a+x)^{k+1}&=\sum_{q=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{q}a(a+qz)^{q-1}(x-qz)^{k+1-q}\tag{1.2}
\end{align*}

OP already integrated (1.1) and obtained after some simplification
\begin{align*}
(a+x)^{k+1}&=\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k+1}{q}a(a+qz)^{q-1}(x-qz)^{k+1-q}\tag{2}\\
&\qquad+(k+1)C(a,z)
\end{align*}
with $C(a,z)$ an integration constant dependent on the constants $a$ and $z$    . Comparison of (2) with (1.2)  shows that $(k+1)C(a,z)$ is the summand with index $q=k+1$, so that we have to show
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{C(a,z)=\frac{a\left(a+(k+1)z\right)^k}{k+1}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
The representation of $C(a,z)$ makes it plausible, that we start using the induction hypothesis (1.1) by letting $x=(k+1)z$. We multiply (1.1) also with $(a+(k+1)z)$ and obtain
\begin{align*}
&(a+(k+1)z)^{k+1}\\
&\qquad=(a+(k+1)z)\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k}{q}a(a+qz)^{q-1}((k+1-q)z)^{k-q}\\
&\qquad=\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k}{q}a(a+qz)^{q}((k+1-q)z)^{k-q}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k}{q}a(a+qz)^{q-1}((k+1-q)z)^{k+1-q}\tag{4.1}\\
\end{align*}
where we use $a+(k+1)z=(a+qz)+((k+1-q)z)$. On the other hand we obtain from (2) by using $\binom{k+1}{q}=\binom{k}{q}+\binom{k}{q-1}$
\begin{align*}
&(a+(k+1)z)^{k+1}\\
&\qquad=\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k+1}{q}a(a+qz)^{q-1}(x-qz)^{k+1-q}\\
&\qquad=\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k}{q}a(a+qz)^{q-1}((k+1-q)z)^{k+1-q}\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k}{q-1}a(a+qz)^{q-1}((k+1-q)z)^{k+1-q}\\
&\qquad\qquad+(k+1)C(a,z)\tag{4.2}
\end{align*}

> Equating (4.1) and (4.2) one of the sums cancels and we get after rearranging
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(k+1)}&\color{blue}{C(a,z)}=\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k}{q}a(a+qz)^q((k+1-q)z)^{k-q}\\
> &\qquad-\sum_{q=0}^{k}\binom{k}{q-1}a(a+qz)^{q-1}((k+1-q)z)^{k+1-q}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^k\left(\binom{k}{q}-\binom{k}{q-1}\frac{(k+1-q)z}{a+qz}\right)
> a(a+qz)^q((k+1-q)z)^{k-q}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^k\left(\binom{k}{q}-\binom{k}{q}\frac{qz}{a+qz}\right)
> a(a+qz)^q((k+1-q)z)^{k-q}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k}{q}\left(1-\frac{qz}{a+qz}\right)
> a(a+qz)^q((k+1-q)z)^{k-q}\\
> &=a\sum_{q=0}^k\binom{k}{q}a(a+qz)^{q-1}((k+1-q)z)^{k-q}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=a(a+(k+1)z)^k}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (3) and so the induction step (1.2) follows. Note, in the last line we again used the induction hypothesis (1.1) with $x=(k+1)z$.

Comment: Thanks, It did not dawn on me that a could set $z=0$ in (1). Why is this a valid option?

Comment: Isn't $C$ a function of both $a$ and $z$? Then you just computed $C(a,0)$ and not $C(a,z)$. Substitute back your $C$, put $(k+1)z=x$ back and see if it is Abel's theorem with $n=k+1$.

Comment: @Gary; Thank you for notifying me, it might be useful to post your version of the answer below...

Comment: @epi163sqrt You just showed that it depends on $a$. Use your formula for $C$ and check if it gives you Abel's formula for the $k+1$ power.

Comment: @epi163sqrt What you showed is that $$(a+x)^{k+1}=x^{k+1}+ \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k+1}{i} a(a+iz)^{i-1}(x-iz)^{k+1-i}+C(k+1)$$ (since $x=z(k+1)$). Now you can see that $C(k+1)$ should equal to the $k+1$th, final term in Abel's formula. But that term is $\frac{{a(a + iz)^k }}{{k + 1}}$ and not $\frac{{a^{k+1} }}{{k + 1}}$ (unless $z=0$). So $C$ depends on $a$, $k$ and $z$ which are all constants with respect to $x$ (which was the integration variable).

Comment: @Aristarchus_: The argument from Gary is sound and my answer needs to be revised. Please unaccept my answer, so that I can delete it.

Comment: @Gary: Answer revised. Thanks for consequently pointing at the flaw. :-)

Comment: I also made a mistake of not replacing $i$ with $k+1$ in my proposed formula for $C$.

Comment: @Gary; Thank you, but what happened to $x^{k+1}$ in $$\begin{align*}
x^{k+1} + \sum_{q=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{q}a(a+qz)^{q-1}(x-qz)^{k+1-q}\tag{1.2}
\end{align*} $$ at the beginning ? Where it transforms to $(a+z(k+1))^{k+1}$

Comment: @Aristarchus_: Note the sum starts with $q=0$ and not with $q=1$. The term with $q=0$ *is* already $x^{k+1}$.